# Enable password expiry notification for single user account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get one particular user account from active directory and for that particular user account password expiry reminder email notification need to be enabled for that i am using below code.

```
$daysbeforeexpirytonotify = 14  
$now = (get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToFileTime()  
$threshold = (get-date).ToUniversalTime().adddays($daysbeforeexpirytonotify).ToFileTime()  

#$users = Get-ADUser -filter { Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False } `

$users = Get-ADUser -identity user-account –Server sisl.specopsdemo1.com -properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",mail `
                    -searchbase "OU=Users,OU=Specops,DC=specopsdemo1,DC=com" |   
   where { $_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" -lt $threshold -and `  
           $_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" -gt $now } |   
   Select-Object "Name",  
                 "Mail",  
                 @{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={  
                       [datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")  
                       }  
                 },  
                 @{Name="DaysToExpiry";Expression={  
                        [int](($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" - $now) / 864000000000)  
                        }  
                 } |  
    sort-object name  
  
$users  
  
foreach ($user in $users) {  
    send-mailmessage -from "it@specopsdemo1.com" `  
                     -smtpserver smtp-server.domain.com `  
                     -to $user.mail `  
                     -subject "Your password will expire in $($user.daystoexpiry) days" `  
                     -body "Your password will expire at $($user.expirydate) (India Standard Time)"   
}
```

However i am getting below error, Please let me know how can i fix this?

```
At C:\Users\raj\Desktop\notification.ps1:30 char:99
+ ... ur password will expire at $($user.expirydate) (India Standard Time)"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Comment: `select -First 1` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, i can't get you, I am looking to configure password expiry email notification for one particular domain account.

Comment: If you know the account name you can change Get-AdUser to only retrieve that account: `Get-ADUser -Identity USERNAME -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",mail -searchbase "OU=Users,OU=Specops,DC=specopsdemo1,DC=com"`

Comment: yes Daniel i know the account name. i will replace `Get-ADUser -filter` line with your code and check it. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel, i have updated the question with recent try.

Comment: Are you getting a different error before that?  Try removing -SearchBase argument from Get-ADUser now that you are using -Identity.  `Get-ADUser -identity user-account –Server sisl.specopsdemo1.com -properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",mail `